# Documenting a private constructor with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, constructor, private, jsdoc

I've got a class where individual methods may be called statically but will return a new instance of class in order to chain, for example:

```
var builder = ns
  .setState('a', 'A')
  .setState('b', 'B');
```

Where `Builder` is defined as such:

```
/** 
 * @module Builder 
 */

/**
 * @class Builder 
 */

/**
 * @private
 */
function Builder() {
  this.state = {
    query: {}
  };
}
Builder.prototype = {
  /**
   * @param {string} k - The key
   * @param {object} v - The value
   * @return {Builder}
   */
  setState: function(k, v) {
    var that = (this instanceof Builder) ? this : new Builder();
    that[k] = v;
    return that;
  }
  // Other properties and methods…
}
```

The `Builder` constructor is *never* supposed to be called explicitly by user code and thus I'd like it not to show up in the docs. However, all of the combinations I've tried with JSDoc tags (e.g. `@private`, `@constructs`, etc.) can't seem to suppress it from the built docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version 3.5.0 of jsDoc, you can use tag [@hideconstructor](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-hideconstructor.html) on the class, telling `jsDoc` not to include the constructor into documentation.

```
/**
 * @class Builder
 *
 * @hideconstructor
 */
function Builder() {
    // implementation
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `@ignore` directive to achieve this. From the docs:

> The `@ignore` tag indicates that a symbol in your code should never appear in the documentation. This tag takes precedence over all others.

http://usejsdoc.org/tags-ignore.html